# getting specific k bits from a Decimal number

Tags: c++, c++14, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a number x  and I want to print decimal of  k bits from x 
suppose I have number 12 
x = 12 
k = 3
binary of 12 is 1100 and k =3 so my resulting new binary will be 100(decimal is 8) ie form last position
I want to display 8 as output

I want to do this with help of << and >> in c++
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it: zero out the last `k` bits, then subtract that from `x`.

```
unsigned int last_k_bits(unsigned int x, unsigned int k) {
    return x - ((x >> k) << k);
}
```

You can also calculate the bitwise `&` of `x` and 1...1 (`k` 1s)

```
unsigned int last_k_bits(unsigned int x, unsigned int k) {
    return x & ((1u << k) - 1);
}
```

Also, `100` is 4 in decimal, not 8

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sparik won't give the correct result when k equals the whole width (e.g. 32), which might or might not matter depending on the application. This is a version that also gives a correct result for that case:

```
unsigned int last_k_bits(unsigned int x, unsigned int k) {
    return x & ~((((k >> 5) - 1) << k));
}
```

Here, `k >> 5` gives 1 if `k` is 32 and 0 otherwise. Subtracting one gives all-ones except for `k` = 32 where it is all-zeros. Shifting by `k` then gives the inverse of the mask we need.